# Matrix preprocessing for linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

It's not clear why I have to standardize a dataset before using `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`. It's not obvious for me why it's must lead to right result despite of normalization raw data.
As a test I have prepared some dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
size = 700
data['x_1'] = x_1
data['x_2'] = x_2
data['y'] = map(lambda i : x_1[i]*7.5 - 2*x_2[i] + noise[i], range(size))
```

where:

```
noise = np.random.normal(0,1,size)
x_1 = np.random.normal(5,2,size)
x_2 = np.random.normal(2,1,size)
```

and then I've tried to find coefficients using LinearRegression with shuffled and standardized matrix:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
df_shuffled = shuffle(data, random_state=123)
X = scale(df_shuffled[df_shuffled.columns[:-1]])
y = df_shuffled["y"]
```

and here is result:

```
linear_regressor.fit(X,y)
(14.951827073780766, 'x_1')
(-1.9171042297858722, 'x_2')
```

After that I've repeated all steps without scale() function and received a better result:

```
(7.5042271168341887, 'x_1')
(-1.9835960918124507, 'x_2')
```

Is it just an exception or I've done some mistakes?

Comment: updated. I've included imports in question.

Comment: Sorry, seems I didn't get your point. without invoke scaling() coeffs are correct.

Comment: @VictorGarbuz, why do you perform shuffling? Regression is aware of data points order. That is because a linear regression is (roughly speaking) a process of "pulling" a line onto a cloud of dots, whose X's are indices and Y's are values. So even if you move any point, you distort the line.

Comment: @Arhad, in my case there is no order. I just tried to add randomisation in data.

Comment: @Arhad, I've receive same result without shuffling

Comment: @pault, I've just tested the code without shuffle. The same results:
X = scale(data[data.columns[:-1]])
y = data["y"]
(14.951827073780768, 'x_1')
(-1.9171042297858716, 'x_2') 
and
X = data[data.columns[:-1]]
y = data["y"]
(7.5042271168341879, 'x_1')
(-1.9835960918124511, 'x_2')

Comment: @pault, got it.

Comment: @VictorGarbuz the issue is that `scale` changes the relationship between the independent variables and the dependent variable. I will write an answer to explain, as there isn't enough room in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Standardizing isn't really a requirement for linear regression. Here's an example where I split the data into train/test splits and then predict on the test.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x_1': np.random.normal(0, 1, size), 'x_2': np.random.normal(2, 1, size)})
>>> df['y'] = map(lambda i: df['x_1'][i] * 7.5 - 2 * df['x_2'][i] + np.random.normal(0, 1, size)[i], range(size))
>>> lr = LinearRegression()
>>> X_scaled = scale(df[['x_1', 'x_2']])
>>> X_ns = df[['x_1', 'x_2']]
>>> y = df['y']
>>> train_X_scaled = X_scaled[:-100]
>>> test_X_scaled = X_scaled[-100:]
>>> train_X_ns = X_ns[:-100]
>>> test_X_ns = X_ns[-100:]
>>> train_y = y[:-100]
>>> test_y = y[-100:]
>>> lr.fit(train_X_scaled, train_y)
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
>>> lr.coef_
array([ 7.38189303, -2.04137514])
>>> lr.predict(test_X_scaled)
array([ -5.12130597, -21.58547658, -10.59483732, -10.56241312,
-16.88790301,   0.61347437,  -7.28207791,  -9.37464865,
-5.12411501, -14.79287322,  -9.84583896,   0.61183408,
-9.00695481,  -0.42201284, -20.50254306,   0.1984764 ,
-9.57419381,   1.39035118,   9.66405865, -10.18972252,
-8.76733834,  -7.33179222, -10.53075411,   0.51671133,
 3.65140463, -16.86740729,   7.86837224,   4.61310894,
-3.80289123, -11.92948864,  -6.55643999, -10.77231532,
 1.97181141,  15.75089958,   2.71987359,  -5.49740398,
-6.59654793,  -6.39042298,  -8.86057313,  12.63031921,
-8.05054779, -11.04476828,  -3.70610232,  -4.81986166,
-3.09909457,  10.3576317 ,  -6.48789854,  -4.05243726,
-4.11076559,  -9.21957658,  -4.36368549,   2.13365208,
-19.24153319,   6.52751487,  -3.48801127,   2.01989782,
-1.00673834, -10.33590131,  -9.25592347, -16.91433355,
 3.58685085,  -6.30149903,  -2.23264539,   6.86114404,
 8.33602945, -14.25656579, -22.24380384, -14.50287259,
-6.64710009, -17.40421316, -12.7734427 ,  -3.76204612,
-0.05843445,  -5.0349674 ,  -6.86404519,  -6.8523112 ,
-14.9479788 ,   1.6120415 ,  -6.24457762,  -7.11712009,
-5.57018237,  -2.89811595,  -5.44008672,   8.19302959,
-1.78437334, -19.32108323,   1.00091276,   4.79161569,
 1.65685676,  -8.68406543,   7.27219645,  -2.90941943,
 2.4613977 ,   2.94533763,  -6.35486958,  -1.01281799,
 2.13959957,  -6.73934486,  -1.65493937,  13.2605013 ])
>>> lr.fit(train_X_ns, train_y)
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
>>> lr.coef_
array([ 7.52554825, -1.98783572])
>>> lr.predict(test_X_ns)
array([ -5.12130597, -21.58547658, -10.59483732, -10.56241312,
-16.88790301,   0.61347437,  -7.28207791,  -9.37464865,
-5.12411501, -14.79287322,  -9.84583896,   0.61183408,
-9.00695481,  -0.42201284, -20.50254306,   0.1984764 ,
-9.57419381,   1.39035118,   9.66405865, -10.18972252,
-8.76733834,  -7.33179222, -10.53075411,   0.51671133,
 3.65140463, -16.86740729,   7.86837224,   4.61310894,
-3.80289123, -11.92948864,  -6.55643999, -10.77231532,
 1.97181141,  15.75089958,   2.71987359,  -5.49740398,
-6.59654793,  -6.39042298,  -8.86057313,  12.63031921,
-8.05054779, -11.04476828,  -3.70610232,  -4.81986166,
-3.09909457,  10.3576317 ,  -6.48789854,  -4.05243726,
-4.11076559,  -9.21957658,  -4.36368549,   2.13365208,
-19.24153319,   6.52751487,  -3.48801127,   2.01989782,
-1.00673834, -10.33590131,  -9.25592347, -16.91433355,
 3.58685085,  -6.30149903,  -2.23264539,   6.86114404,
 8.33602945, -14.25656579, -22.24380384, -14.50287259,
-6.64710009, -17.40421316, -12.7734427 ,  -3.76204612,
-0.05843445,  -5.0349674 ,  -6.86404519,  -6.8523112 ,
-14.9479788 ,   1.6120415 ,  -6.24457762,  -7.11712009,
-5.57018237,  -2.89811595,  -5.44008672,   8.19302959,
-1.78437334, -19.32108323,   1.00091276,   4.79161569,
 1.65685676,  -8.68406543,   7.27219645,  -2.90941943,
 2.4613977 ,   2.94533763,  -6.35486958,  -1.01281799,
 2.13959957,  -6.73934486,  -1.65493937,  13.2605013 ])
```

Scores are also the same:

```
>>> lr.fit(train_X_ns, train_y)
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
>>> lr.score(test_X_ns, test_y)
0.9829300206380267
>>> lr.fit(train_X_scaled, train_y)
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
>>> lr.score(test_X_scaled, test_y)
0.9829300206380267
```

So why standardize? Because it doesn't hurt. In a pipeline, you might add additional steps such as clustering or PCA, which would require scaling. Just remember that if you want to apply scaling, you want to also apply it to your scoring dataset. In this case, it's a requirement to use the [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) because it has a `fit` and `transform`. For my example, I used `scale` because I applied it to both my train and test before splitting. However, in real life scenarios, your future data is unknown so you want to use `StandardScaler` to make the transformations based on the mu and std found from your training set.

Answer (score 2):

`sklearn.preprocessing.scale()` transforms a variable by subtracting the mean (`mu`) and dividing by the standard deviation (`sigma`):

```
x_scaled = (x - mu) / sigma
```

In your case, the `mu` and `sigma` values for `x1` are 5 and 2, respectively. So calling scale, will subtract 5 from each `x1` and divide it by 2.

The shifting doesn't impact the linear regression coefficients- it just changes the intercept. But the scale is different. If the relationship between x1 and y were given by:

```
y = a*x1  # where the coefficient a is a constant
```

and we divide `x1` by 2, then you need to double the coefficient to maintain the same relationship.

In this example, `x2` isn't impacted because it has a `sigma` of 1.

Coefficients/Intercept without scaling:

```
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()
linear_regressor.fit(X,y)
print(linear_regressor.coef_)
print(linear_regressor.intercept_)
#[ 7.48676034 -1.99400201]
#0.0253066229528
```

With scaling:

```
X_scaled = scale(df_shuffled[df_shuffled.columns[:-1]])
linear_regressor2 = LinearRegression()
linear_regressor2.fit(X_scaled,y)
print(linear_regressor2.coef_)
print(linear_regressor2.intercept_)
#[ 14.90368565  -1.94029573]
#33.7451724511
```

In the second case, you are getting the coefficients and intercept for the *scaled* versions of `x1` and `x2`.

This isn't a problem or a bug. All that it means is that if you are using your fitted model to make predictions, you just need to apply the same transformations to the new data.